# how to use a button to change the body color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

i wrote this code to change the mode of the page from regular to light to dark mode and change the color of the body but the buttons doesn't work and i keep getting this message in the debugger

html buttons code

```
   <ul>
             <li> <button type="button" id="l" onclick="myfunction()">Light</button></li>
             <li> <button id="d"> Dark</button> </li>
         </ul>
```

javascript code

```
function myfunction(){ document.body.style.background="red";

}
```

debuggerUncaught

```
ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined 
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

[image]

i tried changing the buttons to divs and changing the function couple of times but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

See If This Helps

```js
function changeColor(e){
    const body = document.body
    body.classList.toggle("dark")
    e.innerText = body.classList.contains("dark") ? "Light" : "Dark"
}
```

```css
  .dark {
      background:black;
      color:white;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="changeColor(this)">Dark</button>

  <br ><br >

  <div class="texts">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>

</body>
```